# Change Payment Method not available for all Azure subscriptions

Tags: azure

For some of my Azure subscriptions I have the option to "Change payment method" when in the Azure account management portal. Other subscriptions do not offer this option, or others such as "Edit Subscription Details".

It is as though the Subscription is not associated with a subscription for billing purposes.

How can I make a payment for this subscription?

Microsoft Support has been very poor helping with this issue.

**Example of a Good Subscription**

[image: A good subscription where I can change payment method]

**Example of a Bad Subscription**

[image]

Comment: Would you outline what sort of assistance you are looking for on Stack Overflow? This sounds like a support issue to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure billing support issue. Not a programming question. You'll need to open a billing support ticket (which is free to do).

Comment: Are you using the service administrator account? A lot of these features are missing from co-administrator accounts...

Comment: I agree it is not a technical programming question, but Microsoft directs users to SO on the [Azure support options page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/). I came to SO looking for help on this issue, so other may too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this issue can only be resolved with help from MS Support.

It was longwinded and involved multiple profiles on commerce.microsoft.com, but the upshot was that once my subscription's status changed to "Warning", Azure removed the menu option that would allow me to resolve the issue myself. Only MS Support could effect the change to resolve it. Crazy!

[image]